# Rails 3, Sortable table columns by linked models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I was recently following http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns to add sortable table columns to my app. It worked great, but some of the columns in my table are things like post.comments.count (obviously posts have many comments). I'd like to be able to sort by the number of comments a post has in the table, but I can't figure out how I'd implement this using the solution in the railscast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a [counter_cache](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter_cache).

Using a migration, create a `comments_count:integer` database field on table `posts`.

Then update your model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Then sort on that column:

```
Post.order(:comments_count)
```

Comment: So technically this answers the count scenario specifically, but is there a method for other linked model data?

Comment: `Foo.join(:bar).order('bar.whatever')`

Comment: Great answers! However, isnt using the .includes a better way to do it than using .join?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be a counter cache column in the case you had mentioned

```
post.comments_count 
# instead of 
post.comments.count
```

Not sure if that will be applicable in every of your cases.